# Java Booleans return do/while

Tags: java, boolean

I'm new to java Booleans and was wondering how I could return true/false within a do/while loop (without it beeing in the main method). Something like this.

```
public class Class1 {

static boolean success = false;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    while(Method1());
}

private static boolean Method1() {
    do {
        //Do something          
    }       
    while (success);
}
```

However, it Java doesn't seem to pick up on success beeing a boolean variable? Could anyone please explain to me..?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're not returning anything from your method.

Comment: I thought I did when I used while(success)?

Comment: while(Method1()); ? why don't you just use do-while in main?

Comment: Only way to return a result is... um... by using `return`.

Comment: @VivekMangal Cause we got an assignment to do it without doing inside the main method.

Comment: @Someuser `Method1()` method is missing a `return` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need that while loop in your `Method1()`. Rearrange your function to something like this:

```
private static boolean Method1() {
    //Do something   
    //if success happened, set it to false       
    return success;
}
```

I also recommend you to use `while(!Method1());`. It makes the Code more understandable when you need to work at it later.

Alternatively change the whole architecture:

```
static boolean success = false;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    while(!success)
      Method1();
}

private static void Method1() {
    //Do something          
    //When Goal reached, set success = true
}
```

I think this is a cleaner way of solving your problem.
Greetings

Comment: Doesn't work like that... https://pastebin.com/bMwgRme8 this is what my code is, and I really don't understand why my teacher would force me to use a boolean method when I just can do it as a void function? I'm trying to understand how I can return success without using return if that makes any sense?

Comment: check the 2nd approach then, should be better with your specific case

Comment: Oh, then go back to my first solution. You just need to customize your code and remove that while in Method1()

Comment: you can't return anything without using return and if your method is boolean, you MUST have to return boolean.